# Converting number into dates

Tags: sas

I have this number `90724` which is actually `24/07/2009`, how can output the number to that date format. `Another example 100821 should 21/08/2010`

```
data want 
    set testData;
format date ddmmyyyy.;
run;
```

Cheers

Comment: Atleast have the courtesy to show what you have tried :/

Comment: have a look I added my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to learn about [Informats](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000197982.htm). Another good introductory source is this [UCLA site](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/modules/dates.htm)

What you really needed to specify is the format in which you have the dates - using the informat `yymmdd6.` It uses a `YearCutOff` option to determine which century a 2-digit year falls into see [Adjusting Dates in a New Century](http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2002/CC05.pdf) & [YEARCUTOFF= System Option](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000197881.htm)

Note: The default is 1920 which spans the 100-year range between 1920 and 2019 - if your dates are outside this range then set the appropritate cutoff value using `OPTIONS YEARCUTOFF=nnnn`;

```
data test;
dateNumber=100821; ProperDate=input(put(dateNumber,6.), yymmdd6.); output;/*ProperDate= 21AUG2010*/
dateNumber=90724; ProperDate=input(put(dateNumber,6.) , yymmdd6.); output;/*ProperDate=24JUL2009*/
format ProperDate date9.;
run;
```